# django loading data from fixture after backward migration / loaddata is using model schema not database schema

Tags: django, django-south

I have recenty came across a problem while importing older data than my current model schema. Flow which I use and lead to error:

- dumpdata with python manage.py dumpdata -> 0002
- make some modifications to model
- generate migration with python manage.py schemamigration app_name --auto -> 0003
- run migration
- play with database
- migrate to 0002
- loaddata generate SQL in which I have current (migration 0003) fields, and cause failing loaddata process (mpoly is added field)

> ```
>   File "/usr/local/lib/python2.6/dist-packages/django/db/backends/postgresql_psycopg2/base.py",
> ```
>
> line 44, in execute
>           return self.cursor.execute(query, args)
>       DatabaseError: column "mpoly" of relation "localization_province" does
>   not exist
>       LINE 1: ...e" ("id", "name", "slug", "mpoly") V...

- commenting changes in models.py done before 0003, make all working ok

**Is there any way to avoid playing with models after backward migration if I want to loaddata?**

Maybe I'm missing something really obvious...

PS: I'm using South 7.3, Django 1.2.3 and PostgreSQL 8.4 as database backend.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

[Alex Vidal](https://stackoverflow.com/users/237211/alex-vidal) proposed a nice quick fix for this when it bit us at our job. It requires Gary Bernhardt's [Dingus](https://github.com/garybernhardt/dingus) library. Once we have time we'll factor out the Dingus dependency and submit a pull request to South, but if you're in a bind right now this may get you out of it:

```
from dingus import patch


def loaddata(orm, fixture_name):
    _get_model = lambda model_identifier: orm[model_identifier]

    with patch('django.core.serializers.python._get_model', _get_model):
        from django.core.management import call_command
        call_command("loaddata", fixture_name)
```

Usage:

```
from apps.common.utils import loaddata


class Migration(DataMigration):
    def forwards(self, orm):
        loaddata(orm, "initial_fjords.json")
```

We've tested only in Django 1.3 so far. **Edit**: I checked Django's `_get_model` history and this should work with Django 0.95 and up.

Comment: Thank you for this answer. We use the mock library (not dingus) and it works very nice.

Comment: Thanks! It works perfectly and solved a lot of data migration problems.

Answer (score 3):

I find that it is best to keep any fixtures I have in line with the current version of the code. So upon creating migration 0003 you do a [data migration](http://south.aeracode.org/docs/tutorial/part3.html#data-migrations) and a new `dumpdata`, replacing fixture 0002. When you create your data migration, make sure you do both forwards and backwards, that way you'll end up with the correct data when you migrate back to 0002.

When you do the data migration, make sure you access all models through the `orm` object, otherwise you end up with errors similar to what you're already experiencing.

If you want to actually run your django code with the old data (version 0002) for some reason, then your models need to match your database. That would mean checking out an appropriate version of the code using whatever code versioning you're using (git, hg, svn...). If you're trying to solve a problem "back in time" you probably want to branch at that point too.

See also [south's documentation comments on fixtures](http://south.aeracode.org/docs/fixtures.html)

Here's an idea, inspired by that link above: "the best thing to do is to write a new migration to load the fixture in". What about loading your fixture (which you already have) from a migration, rather than `loaddata`. You would still need to create a data migration and use the `orm` object to manually load the data. You can make use of django's [serialization functions](http://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.3/topics/serialization/), which is exactly what `loaddata` [does](http://code.djangoproject.com/browser/django/trunk/django/core/management/commands/loaddata.py#L168).

With respect to why `loaddata` uses the model version and not the database version: `loaddata` is a [django management command](http://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/django-admin/#loaddata-fixture-fixture), with no knowledge of what south is doing. Because of that, it needs to remain database agnostic and use django's ORM. You can always [write your own management command](http://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/howto/custom-management-commands/) if you need to do something more specific - potentially pulling out some of south's orm versioning, or doing a database specific loaddata that reads the schema directly from the database. I think the solution in the previous paragraph will be a lot less work though.

Comment: I see your way. But I don't really like it, cause in my situation each dump is over 25MB. It simply would be inconvinient to prepare datadump for each migration I create.

Comment: I still do not see WHY LOADDATA takes fields from model.py instead of simply creating proper SQL commands for data from fixture?

Comment: I've edit the answer with some further thoughts. Hope that helps to clear things up?

Comment: The line: "Because of that, it needs to remain database agnostic and use django's ORM." Tells me everything! I've just came to such conclusion... I wanted to share my thoughts but I see you were faster. Thanks! - I'll post back with solution I decided to use.

Comment: I found ticket on http://south.aeracode.org/ticket/334 in which they want to enable fake orm loaddata. But milestone 1.0 is so far away. Maybe I'll make research if it couldn't be simply done during this weekend...

Answer (score 2):

Late to this discussion but hope this is helpful. Really you have two approaches you can take:

- Load the data early on in your migrations and then use data
  migrations to change it any time you have a schema migration. This has the advantage that you are testing your data migrations as you go.
- Load the data as a fixture, which will always use your current models
  and therefore require you to keep your fixtures up to date.

In addition to the approaches above, you can load data by using dumpscript (available as part of django-command-extensions) to dump out your fixture in python. From there you need to edit the fixture to use the ORM available within the migration, rather than your Django models. This is usually most useful if you don't have too much data.

See: http://south.aeracode.org/attachment/ticket/1010/fixtures.diff