# Django South Schema migration with fixture pre-loading

Tags: python, django, django-south

So the issue is that I have a Django project running fine now.

I need to make two schema changes, A and B.

For some reason, I need to load some fixture to database after I apply migration A and then apply migration B.

I can do it manually, of course. Like:

```
./manage.py migrate my_app 0001
./manage.py loaddata my_fixture.json
./manage.py migrate my_app 0002
```

and that works fine.

However, in production, I want to deploy my project with script automatically. I don't want to add too many manual step in it.

My ideal solution is that I can automatically populate my fixture after my schema change (maybe with some special option parameters).

Does anyone have an idea how to do it?

PS: I may not giving enough info of my problem. So if you think problem itself is too vague, leave the comment, and let me see what I can do to make it more clear.

UPDATE:
I have marked Serafeim as correct answer.  Robert Jørgensgaard Engdahl points out a good point, which can be explained detailed in following post
 [django loading data from fixture after backward migration / loaddata is using model schema not database schema](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5472925/django-loading-data-from-fixture-after-backward-migration-loaddata-is-using-mo?rq=1)

However, the problem we have is not exactly same. My schema A is to create a new table and won't change it in foreseeable future. migration B is to add a new column to another table which point to the table created by A. And that is why I need to pre-populate some data in new table (for some other complicate reason, I don't want to explain this too much). And I have tested the solution from Serafeim, it works.

HOWEVER, if anyone encounter a similar situation, look at the post shared by Robert Jørgensgaard Engdahl to understand the downside of this solution before you take it. Thanks again for both of answer providers!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should use south data migrations:

http://south.readthedocs.org/en/latest/tutorial/part3.html#data-migrations.

South already has a recipy for loading your data in http://south.readthedocs.org/en/latest/fixtures.html.

After you create migration 0001, create an empty migration that will be used to load your data with:

```
./manage.py datamigration appname load_myfixture
```

Then, in the 0002_load_myfixture.py migration module modify the `forwards` migration like this:

```
def forwards(self, orm):
    from django.core.management import call_command
    call_command("loaddata", "my_fixture.json")
```

You don't need to implement the `backwards` migration.

Comment: sound promising, let me have a try

Comment: Wont work. Check out this related post: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5472925/django-loading-data-from-fixture-after-backward-migration-loaddata-is-using-mo?rq=1

The loaddata command, no mater how you call it, will use the Django ORM and not the South ORM, so later migrations will invalidate this one.

Comment: @RobertJørgensgaardEngdahl, Thanks for your advice. And I think I understand the harmful part of this solution. There is a reason I still use it, see the update.

Answer (score 0):

Introducing new rows in any migration should be considered harmful: It becomes impossible to "reset" the migrations; i.e. make a release with no ORM changes, but all migrations replaced with 0001_initial migrations. In long lived projects you want to keep this option open.